# Converting tensorflow to keras Conv2D

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to convert a simple tensorflow network to keras and get reproducible results, using MNIST data.

With just a single Dense layer I can do this, however when I add a Conv2D layer the results from tensorflow and keras are different, and I cannot figure out why.

The tensorflow implementation (a part of the tensorflow MNIST tutorial) is as follows:

```
  with tf.name_scope('conv1'):
     W_conv1 = weight_variable([2, 2, 1, 32])
     b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])
     h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)

  def weight_variable(shape):
   """weight_variable generates a weight variable of a given shape."""
      initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1, seed=0)
      return tf.Variable(initial)

 def bias_variable(shape):
 """bias_variable generates a bias variable of a given shape."""
    initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
    return tf.Variable(initial)
```

The Keras implementation is as follows:

```
 ki = TruncatedNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=0.1, seed=0)
 bi = Constant(value=0.1)
 net = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(2, 2), activation='relu', 
              kernel_initializer=ki, bias_initializer=bi)(input_image)
```

The issues is with this layer only, as if I remove it the network performance is the same in both cases, epoch per epoch.

ALSO: if I change the kernel size to (1,1) in both cases then the performance is identical, only for larger sizes it changes.

Does anybody know what is different in the keras implementation, that might cause this.  (It is running on top of tensorflow, and on the same machine in each case).

Thank you.

Comment: It can be that your seed values are different by default, i.e. that the initial weights for Conv2D in tf and in Keras don't start at the same values